# this is my trigger if custom setting value become 4 then custom setting value updated to 2 (custom label value==4)

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger Leadassignmentbyroundrobin on Lead(after insert) {
    set <string> emailSet = new set <string> ();
    set <string> phoneSet = new set <string>();

        Boolean updateflag = false;
        RoundRobinSetting__c settings = RoundRobinSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
        Integer currentSeq = Integer.valueOf(settings.Number__c);

        map<integer,id> usermap = new map<integer,id>();
        list<user> userlst = [select id,Round_Robin_id__c from user where isActive=true];
           for(user u:userlst){
               if(u.Round_Robin_id__c !=null){
                   usermap.put(integer.valueof(u.Round_Robin_id__c),u.id);
               }
           }

    If(trigger.isinsert) 
        for (lead L: trigger.new) {
            if (l.LeadSource == 'online' && (l.Email != null || l.Phone != null)) {
                if(l.Email != null)
                    emailSet.add(l.Email);    
                if(l.Phone != null)
                    phoneSet.add(l.Phone);
            }
        }


    map <string,Lead> existingEmailLeadMap = new map <string,Lead>();
    map <string,Lead> existingPhoneLeadMap = new map <string,Lead>();

    for (lead l: [SELECT id, LeadSource, Email, OwnerId,Your_Enquiry__c, Phone FROM Lead WHERE (Email IN: emailSet OR Phone IN: phoneSet) AND id NOT IN:trigger.new order by LastModifiedDate asc]) {

        if(l.Email != null && !existingEmailLeadMap.containsKey(l.Email))       
            existingEmailLeadMap.put(l.Email, L);

        if(l.Phone != null && !existingPhoneLeadMap.containsKey(l.Phone))       
            existingPhoneLeadMap .put(l.Phone, L);        
    }


    map<string ,account> existingEmailAccountMap = new map <string,account>();
    map<string ,account> existingPhoneAccountMap = new map <string,account>();
    map<string ,account> existingSpEmailAccountMap = new map <string,account>();
    map<string ,account> existingSpPhoneAccountMap = new map <string,account>();

    for (account a: [SELECT id, OwnerId, Phone__c,Email__c,Spouse_Email__c,Spouse_Phone__c FROM account 
                                    WHERE ( Email__c IN: emailSet OR Spouse_Email__c IN: emailSet OR 
                                            Phone__c IN: phoneSet OR Spouse_Phone__c IN: phoneSet)
                                      order by LastModifiedDate asc]) {

        if(a.Email__c != null && !existingEmailAccountMap.containsKey(a.Email__c))       
            existingEmailAccountMap.put(a.Email__c, a);

        if(a.Phone__c != null && !existingPhoneAccountMap.containsKey(a.Phone__c))       
            existingPhoneAccountMap.put(a.Phone__c, a);        

        if(a.Spouse_Email__c != null && !existingSpEmailAccountMap.containsKey(a.Spouse_Email__c))       
            existingSpEmailAccountMap.put(a.Spouse_Email__c, a);

        if(a.Spouse_Phone__c != null && !existingSpPhoneAccountMap.containsKey(a.Spouse_Phone__c))       
            existingSpPhoneAccountMap.put(a.Spouse_Phone__c, a);        

    }    

    List <Task> tasks = new List <Task>();
    map<Id, Lead> newLeads = new map<Id, Lead>([Select id,OwnerId from Lead where Id in: trigger.new]);

    for (Lead l: trigger.new) {

        if(l.Email != null && existingEmailLeadMap.containsKey(l.Email)){
            lead exisLeadRec = existingEmailLeadMap.get(l.Email);
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whoid = exisLeadRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisLeadRec.ownerId;
            ts.Description = existingEmailLeadMap.get(l.email).Your_Enquiry__c;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            tasks.add(ts);

        }else if(l.Phone != null && existingEmailLeadMap.containsKey(l.Phone)){
            lead exisLeadRec = existingEmailLeadMap.get(l.Phone);
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whoid = exisLeadRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisLeadRec.ownerId;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            ts.Description = existingEmailLeadMap.get(l.email).Your_Enquiry__c;
            tasks.add(ts);

        }else if(l.Email != null && existingEmailAccountMap.containsKey(l.Email )){
            account exisaccRec = existingEmailAccountMap.get(l.Email );
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whatid = exisaccRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisaccRec.ownerId;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            tasks.add(ts);


        }
        else if(l.Phone != null && existingPhoneAccountMap.containsKey(l.Phone)){
            account exisaccRec = existingEmailAccountMap.get(l.Phone);
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whatid = exisaccRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisaccRec.ownerId;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            tasks.add(ts);


        }else if(l.Email != null && existingSpEmailAccountMap.containsKey(l.Email )){
            account exisaccRec = existingSpEmailAccountMap.get(l.Email );
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whatid = exisaccRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisaccRec.ownerId;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            tasks.add(ts);




           }else if(l.phone!= null && existingSpPhoneAccountMap.containsKey(l.phone)){
            account exisaccRec = existingSpPhoneAccountMap.get(l.phone);
            task ts = new task();              
            ts.Whatid = exisaccRec.id;
            ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
            ts.Subject = 'New Enquiry';
            ts.Priority = 'Normal';
            ts.OwnerId = exisaccRec.ownerId;
            ts.Status = 'Open';
            tasks.add(ts);


        }

        else{
           if(trigger.isinsert){
               if(l.LeadSource == 'online'){
                   if(newleads.containskey(l.id)){
                       updateflag =true;
                   if(usermap.containskey(currentSeq)){
                       newleads.get(l.id).ownerid=usermap.get(currentSeq);

                   } 

                    if(currentSeq==integer.valueof(label.lastSequenceNo)){                  
                       currentSeq=1;   
                    } 

                          currentSeq++;   
                }
             }
           }  

        } 
    }
          if(updateflag){
              update newleads.values();
          }

            settings.Number__c=decimal.valueof(currentSeq);
            Update settings;


    if (tasks != null && tasks.size() > 0) {
        insert tasks;
    }



}
```

Comment: Hello Jatin, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Your post would be dramatically improved if you **[edit]** it to add a description in the body of your post of what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck. It is also a good idea to try to make your title concise and informative, of which it is neither currently.

Answer (score 1):

seems this would do it:

```
settings.Number__c= currentSeq == 4 ? 2 : decimal.valueof(currentSeq);
```

I have not taken into account any other issues in your code. The answer is per your question directly as it is stated